# Using Objective C library in Swift : Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PRCertification

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

So I want to use a private Objective-C library in a Swift Project.
I will call that library `PRCertification`.

I was trying to use one of its methods which goes sth like `PRCertification.shared().certificate()`.

When I run on my iPhone, it keeps giving me an error : `Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PRCertification`.

But it's working fine with iOS Simulator.

Why is that? And how do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: In your target's General settings, do you have your library included in the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes I did. What could be the issue?

Comment: Not sure, that was just the first thing to check.  How is your library packaged (framework, dylib, lib, ...)?

Comment: It's a framework

Comment: I can't think of much else to check.  Did the framework build for the right architecture?  You can also examine the link command to see that the framework was referenced.  Or look inside the app bundle to verify it's really there.  (Since it works in the simulator, it's hard to imagine a framework code problem.)